# Create Bundle Product link - Not found, missing

Tags: commerce

I have done a basic install of Drupal v7.43 with Commerce Kickstart (commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.34)
Both Commerce Bundle modules are enabled.

In "Add Product" actions I cannot find the "Bundle Product" link in order to create a new Bundle Product with some of the existing (previous added) Bundle Groups.

Also, the "Create Bundle Group" link is missing but I found it in the page: /admin/commerce/products/add.

Why are they missing?

Answer (score 0):

They are missing because of how Kickstart manages it's menus.

The easiest way to fix this is to just disable the Commerce Kickstart Menus (commerce_kickstart_menus) module. You may need to clear all of your caches, but you should see the other items start to show up again.

Comment: I did a clean Drupal 7 setup, with Drupal Commerce and Commerce Bundle modules (not the Kickstart distribution) and the problem persists.

Becides, when I disable the Kickstart menus the administration menu at the top (black) becames unresponsive! Does not working the links when the mouse is over them. Only a few working in a certain spot only.